# Why is the look of the activity different in the Android Studio preview than on the device?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, device, preview

I created an navigation drawer activity and found that its content page looks different in the preview.

[This is the preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6R4B.png)

[And this is the AVD appearance (it looks like a real device too).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXQue.png)

XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.xy.xy.HomePage">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/TestMenuImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg1"
        tools:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:background="@color/hbm_text_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TestMenuName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TestMenuButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What do you think where the problem is?

Comment: are you using nexus 4 in both places ??

Comment: try using fitXy instead of centerCrop imageView..

Comment: No, I use Galaxy Nexus at the AVD, but I tried the one for preview and the same problem. https://imgur.com/4LKgX7l

Comment: Try removing tools:context="com.xy.xy.HomePage" and then refresh your preview and see if it matches the result on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in ImageView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.xy.xy.HomePage">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/TestMenuImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:background="@color/hbm_text_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TestMenuName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TestMenuButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

That's probably a little bug with ImageViews´ previews in Android Studio,

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the background to the RelativeLayout is not visible for some reason. https://imgur.com/nm58bpp Maybe you have some idea why not?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see you've included the style file and it does appear that your app is running the same style (AppTheme) as your preview so I think we can possibly rule out that as a culprit.

I doubt this makes a difference but I noticed your preview is running api 27 and your device is running api 27.

Try removing the 
    `tools:context="com.xy.xy.HomePage"` and see if it makes a difference.

---

The preview can only show you the current view. It doesn't know the parent view. The **child view may have a parent view that constricts the size of the child view**. Let's say that your image is set to width="match_parent". In this case, the preview may expand the image to fill the full width but at runtime your image my be placed inside a parent with a width="100dp" which would cause the image to have a width of only 100dp. Padding and margin of the parent view can also cause an issue.

If this isn't the problem then it may be a styling issue. I'd have to see more of your Theme and Style setup in order to know for sure. Your preview might be showing you a different style/theme than what you are actually using at runtime.

Comment: I also thought about it because of the parent. That's why I called him directly: setContentView(R.layout.content_home_page)

Comment: I tried with 26 and without tools:context="com.xy.xy.HomePage", but there is no change. And Thanks for the help it was useful, but I think I will use the fitXY

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Best of luck!